# How to rotate the entire display in Qt in C++

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, qwidget

I'm working on a Project where I'd like to rotate my display by 90° from a horizontal view to vertical.

How can I rotate the `QWidget` or the Window?

Comment: which qt version you use? is it embedded qt?

Comment: you might find this implementation interesting - https://github.com/archerabi/Qt-Rotating-Widget

Comment: i'm using qt4.8 and yes it is embedded qt